# SharePoint Online asset library link to video not working

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created an Asset Library on my SharePoint Online (2013) site, but I am unable to follow the steps to add a link to a video.

In the Library, you have the options to create a New Video, and then there is an option to 'Provide a link to a video.' The description here says to "Paste a hyperlink to a video file that lives on a file share or an external site:"

Whether I provide the link to a video hosted on Youtube, Vimeo, or our private flash server, I get the same error message "*filename* is not a video file."

It seems like this should be simple; is there something I am missing?

Comment: I get the same result in my SP 2013 assets library. But if I choose the option Provide code to embed a video from the web and paste the Embed code of the video from YouTube it works.

Comment: Thanks; that seems to work for the YouTube and Vimeo videos, but I can't seem to embed my flash server videos.